# Multiple row select ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have grid with RowSelectionModel:

```
selModel: {
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    mode: 'MULTI'
}
```

How to select many rows in grid? Now I can select only one record with `me.getViewModel().get('record')`:

```
var me = this;

// Ask user to confirm this action
Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm Delete', 'Are you sure you want to delete this asset_objects?', function(result) {

    // User confirmed yes
    if (result == 'yes') {

        var record = me.getViewModel().get('record'),
            store = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('asset_objects');

        // Delete record from store
        store.remove(record);

        // Sync remote store
        store.sync();

        // Hide display
        me.showView('selectMessage');

    }

});
```

How I bind selected records to the viewModel:

```
select: function(rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
    // Set selected record
    this.getViewModel().set('record', record);

    // Show details
    this.showView('details');
}
```

Comment: `me.getViewModel().get('record')` just get value from the viewModel. Please, show how you bind selected records to the viewModel.

Comment: `select: function(rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
    // Set selected record
    this.getViewModel().set('record', record);

    // Show details
    this.showView('details');
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Ext.selection.RowModel.getSelection()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html#method-getSelection), like this

```
select: function (rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
    this.getViewModel().set('record', rowmodel.getSelection());

}
```

or instead of [`select ( this, record, index, eOpts )`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html#event-select) event, where `record` is **last** selected record, you can use [`selectionchange ( this, selected, eOpts )`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.RowModel.html#event-selectionchange) event, where `selected` is all selected records.

*Keep in mind that `selectionchange` event is triggered when you select and **deselect** records and the value can be an empty array.*