# ExtJS 6 Bind grid selection to the viewModel

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I want to bind grid selection to the viewModel.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36040368) there is an example for single selection mode:

```
viewModel: {
    formulas: {
        selection: {
            bind: '{g.selection}',
            get: function (selection) {
                return selection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I use:

```
selModel: {
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    mode: 'MULTI'
},
```

viewModel `selection` contains only last selected record and I expect both records in array, like `.getSelection()` returns. Any suggestions?

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27kj).

*Of course, I can manually set viewModel attribute value (for example as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46528485/2667065)), but I ask how this can be achieved through the binding mechanism.*

Comment: The fiddle works for me. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alexander If you select both records in the grid, viewModel `selection` contains only last selected record. I expect both records in array, like `.getSelection()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes to your [code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ol) to add multiple selected records to a ViewModel property **array**, using `formulas` as well as `initViewModel()` method. See if it's helpful.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks, but it doesnt work if you deselect row.

Comment: [Modified it](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ol). Works now for deselected rows also.

Comment: @AmitaSuri, seems like modified code still not working for deselect